# JSON stringify is adding backslashes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, stringify

When the stringified string is sent to request directly, it is not getting added any slashes.

```
    var data = { "A": "Aa", "B": "Bb", "C": "Cc" }; // This is JSON object
        data = JSON.stringify(data); // Getting stringified
    var obj = {method: "POST", 
               url: 'http://..XX..XXX.....com',
               data: data // String is being sent as it is
              };
   $http(obj);// Have no slashes added
//Output: {"A":"Aa","B":"Bb","C":"Cc"}
```

But if the stringified string is set value as property of object and object is sent to server, the string is having backslashes.

```
        var data = { "A": "Aa", "B": "Bb", "C": "Cc" };
            data = JSON.stringify(data);
        var obj  = {method: "POST", 
                   url: 'XXX',
                   data: { // String is being sent as a value of object property "Values"
                       "Values": data 
                      }
                  };
       $http(obj);//Slashes are added

//output: {"Values":"{\"A\":\"Aa\",\"B\":\"Bb\",\"C\":\"Cc\"}"}
```

Can somebody take a look once?

Comment: Since you're giving Angular an Object with its `data` option in the 2nd snippet, the values are being double-encoded – once by you and once by `$http`. Your use of `JSON.stringify()` likely isn't necessary.

Answer (score 7):

If you stringify its the right behaviour. Cause now it's not an object anymore. Why not sending it complete to the server like this. Data could be a string or an object

```
var data = { "A": "Aa", "B": "Bb", "C": "Cc" };
var obj  = {method: "POST", 
               url: 'XXX',
               data: data
              };
$http(obj);
```

If you have to send it as string. Then you have to json_decode it at the server.

Comment: No, I have other properties in the same data object where in every property of string type. Thus the Values object need to be sent as a string.

Comment: If you have to send it as string. Then you have to json_decode it at the server, to get an object again.

Comment: @RamaRaoM If the value of `"Values"` needs to be a string, then the backslashes are necessary to distinguish which double-quotes are characters in the string (with backslash) and which are syntax (string literal delimiters). That's unavoidable.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Then where should the slashes be removed? At server end?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski As we see the example, the Values object is stringified only once. I guess $http is stringifying the total data object one more time.

Comment: I want to write to a json file and have the backslash problem. without `stringify` I get `The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received an instance of Array`